# How to reference certain column fields of an MS Access table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a Microsoft Access 2010 table with 3 columns.

The first column contains the numerical sequential primary key ID
The 2nd contains site names.
The 3rd contains yes/no for each site.

I want to do a loop through the 2nd column to perform an action for every field in column 2 where the entry in column 3 is 'Yes'.

The code I am trying to use which isn't working for me is

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("table1")
Set rs2 = rs.Fields("Column2")
set rs3 = rs.fields("Column3")

For each fld in rs2
If rs3.fields = "Yes" then
```

"The action code would follow here etc etc"

```
Next fld


End if
```

`Loop`

The code doesn't seem to like  "For each fld in rs2"

I would appreciate any help with this

Many Thanks

Comment: If `column3` is a YesNo there is a very good chance it equals 0 or -1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first recordset already has all the fields.

```vb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("table1")
Do While Not rs.EOF
    ' Alternatively: rs("Column3")
    If rs!Column3 = "Yes" Then
       ' stuff
    End If
    ' Next record
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

But: what you want to do in a Recordset loop can most probably be done easier and more efficient in SQL with an UPDATE query.

Comment: Thanks Andre, that's exactly what I was after.

Comment: @JDT - *"that's exactly what I was after"* - Then please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/238021) this answer.